# Toggle true/false using vuex modules?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i am using vuex modules and i have a module named customer.js. In that i have a state showName which is by default set to false. I set a mutation to toggle that state. and in my about.vue file i have a button that calls that mutation but everytime i try to run that mutation, it gives me an error message  Property or method "showCustomerName" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

> In my customer.js module

```
enter code here:    state: {
     showName:false,
 },
  mutations: {
    showCustomerName : state => {
      state.showName = !state.showName
      console.log('works??!!!')
   }
 },
 actions: {

 }
})
```

In my about.vue file

```
 <template>
    <div>
   <button @click="showCustomerName">Click Me</button>
   </div>
  </template>


 <script>
   import {mapMutations} from "vuex"

 export default {
 methods : {
   ...mapMutations ([
    "customer/showCustomerName"
    ])
  }
 }
 </script>
```

I would assume this would work, but not sure what i am doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so figured it out, instead of `...mapMutations ([
    "customer/showCustomerName"
    ])`

change to

```
...mapMutations ('customer',{
showCustomerName: "showCustomerName"
})
```

Comment: Can also be an array if you don't need to rename it: ...mapMutations ('customer', ['showCustomerName'])